# Remove duplicates while ignoring blank values and adding LineAmount in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a requirement where I need to remove duplicate SGSRollupItemName while ignoring SGSRollupItemName which are blank and adding the LineAmount of the duplicate SGSRollupItemName. I have written the code to remove duplicate SGSRollupItemName, although it is removing duplicate SGSRollupItemName but it is also removing SGSRollupItemName which are not duplicate and which are having blank value.
Below is the input xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <Invoice>
        <InvoiceLines>
            <LineAmount>200.00</LineAmount>
            <SGSRollupItemName>Test</SGSRollupItemName>
            <SGSRollupItemNotes>PT</SGSRollupItemNotes>
        </InvoiceLines>
        <InvoiceLines>
            <LineAmount>300.00</LineAmount>
            <SGSRollupItemName>Test1</SGSRollupItemName>
            <SGSRollupItemNotes>PT</SGSRollupItemNotes>
        </InvoiceLines>
        <InvoiceLines>
            <LineAmount>250.00</LineAmount>
            <SGSRollupItemName>Test</SGSRollupItemName>
            <SGSRollupItemNotes>PT</SGSRollupItemNotes>
        </InvoiceLines>
        <InvoiceLines>
            <LineAmount>400.00</LineAmount>
            <SGSRollupItemName></SGSRollupItemName>
            <SGSRollupItemNotes></SGSRollupItemNotes>
        </InvoiceLines>
        <InvoiceLines>
            <LineAmount>500.00</LineAmount>
            <SGSRollupItemName></SGSRollupItemName>
            <SGSRollupItemNotes></SGSRollupItemNotes>
        </InvoiceLines>
    </Invoice>
</root>
```

Here is the xslt code that I am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
  <xsl:key name="dups" match="InvoiceLines[normalize-space(SGSRollupItemName)]" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', SGSRollupItemName)" />

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <cXML>
      <Header/>
      <Request xslt="XML">
        <InvoiceDetailRequest>
          <InvoiceDetailRequestHeader>
          </InvoiceDetailRequestHeader>
          <xsl:for-each select="Invoice/InvoiceLines[normalize-space(SGSRollupItemName)][not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('dups',concat(generate-id(..), '|', SGSRollupItemName))[1]))]">
            <InvoiceDetailOrder>
              <InvoiceDetailItem >
                <xsl:variable name="numbers">
                  <xsl:for-each select="key('dups', concat(generate-id(..), '|',SGSRollupItemName ))/LineAmount">
                    <num>
                      <xsl:value-of select="translate(., ',', '')"/>
                    </num>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:variable>
                <UnitPrice>
                  <Money>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(exsl:node-set($numbers)/num),'0.00,#')"/>
                  </Money>
                </UnitPrice>
                <NetAmount>
                  <Money>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(exsl:node-set($numbers)/num),'0.00,#')"/>
                  </Money>
                </NetAmount>
                <Comments>
                  <xsl:value-of select="./SGSRollupItemName/text()"/>
                </Comments>
                <Comments>
                  <xsl:value-of select ="./SGSRollupItemNotes/text()"/>
                </Comments>
              </InvoiceDetailItem>
            </InvoiceDetailOrder>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </InvoiceDetailRequest>
      </Request>
    </cXML>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below is the output I am getting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cXML>
    <Header />
    <Request xslt="XML">
        <InvoiceDetailRequest>
            <InvoiceDetailRequestHeader />
            <InvoiceDetailOrder>
                <InvoiceDetailItem>
                    <UnitPrice>
                        <Money>450.00</Money>
                    </UnitPrice>
                    <NetAmount>
                        <Money>450.00</Money>
                    </NetAmount>
                    <Comments>Test</Comments>
                    <Comments>PT</Comments>
                </InvoiceDetailItem>
            </InvoiceDetailOrder>
        </InvoiceDetailRequest>
    </Request>
</cXML>
```

But below is the expected output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cXML>
    <Header />
    <Request xslt="XML">
        <InvoiceDetailRequest>
            <InvoiceDetailRequestHeader />
            <InvoiceDetailOrder>
                <InvoiceDetailItem>
                    <UnitPrice>
                        <Money>450.00</Money>
                    </UnitPrice>
                    <NetAmount>
                        <Money>450.00</Money>
                    </NetAmount>
                    <Comments>Test</Comments>
                    <Comments>PT</Comments>
                </InvoiceDetailItem>
            </InvoiceDetailOrder>
            <InvoiceDetailOrder>
                <InvoiceDetailItem>
                    <UnitPrice>
                        <Money>300.00</Money>
                    </UnitPrice>
                    <NetAmount>
                        <Money>300.00</Money>
                    </NetAmount>
                    <Comments>Test1</Comments>
                    <Comments>PT</Comments>
                </InvoiceDetailItem>
            </InvoiceDetailOrder>
            <InvoiceDetailOrder>
                <InvoiceDetailItem>
                    <UnitPrice>
                        <Money>400.00</Money>
                    </UnitPrice>
                    <NetAmount>
                        <Money>400.00</Money>
                    </NetAmount>
                    <Comments></Comments>
                    <Comments></Comments>
                </InvoiceDetailItem>
            </InvoiceDetailOrder>
            <InvoiceDetailOrder>
                <InvoiceDetailItem>
                    <UnitPrice>
                        <Money>500.00</Money>
                    </UnitPrice>
                    <NetAmount>
                        <Money>500.00</Money>
                    </NetAmount>
                    <Comments></Comments>
                    <Comments></Comments>
                </InvoiceDetailItem>
            </InvoiceDetailOrder>
        </InvoiceDetailRequest>
    </Request>
</cXML>
```

Can you please suggest what I am doing wrong in the xslt code

Comment: Please reduce the examples to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem and add the expected result - see: [mcve].

Comment: I have reduced the example to minimal reproducible example

Comment: You say you want to "ignore SGSRollupItemName which are blank" - but those items do appear in your expected output. ??

Comment: By ignoring I mean to say, I do not want to remove SGSRollupItemName which are blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not entirely clear. Looking at the expected output it would seem you want to group lines where `SGSRollupItemName` is not blank, and list the lines that are blank separately.

If so, consider the following **simplified** example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="dups" match="InvoiceLines" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', SGSRollupItemName)"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <cXML>
        <!-- group non-blank items -->
        <xsl:for-each select="Invoice/InvoiceLines[normalize-space(SGSRollupItemName)][generate-id() = generate-id(key('dups', concat(generate-id(..), '|', SGSRollupItemName))[1])]">
            <InvoiceDetailOrder>
                <Money>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('dups', concat(generate-id(..), '|',SGSRollupItemName ))/LineAmount),'0.00')"/>
                </Money>
                <Comments>
                    <xsl:value-of select="SGSRollupItemName"/>
                </Comments>
            </InvoiceDetailOrder>
        </xsl:for-each> 
        <!-- list blank items -->
        <xsl:for-each select="Invoice/InvoiceLines[not(normalize-space(SGSRollupItemName))]">
            <InvoiceDetailOrder>
                <Money>
                    <xsl:value-of select="LineAmount"/>
                </Money>
                <Comments>
                    <xsl:value-of select="SGSRollupItemName"/>
                </Comments>
            </InvoiceDetailOrder>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </cXML>
</xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cXML>
  <InvoiceDetailOrder>
    <Money>450.00</Money>
    <Comments>Test</Comments>
  </InvoiceDetailOrder>
  <InvoiceDetailOrder>
    <Money>300.00</Money>
    <Comments>Test1</Comments>
  </InvoiceDetailOrder>
  <InvoiceDetailOrder>
    <Money>400.00</Money>
    <Comments/>
  </InvoiceDetailOrder>
  <InvoiceDetailOrder>
    <Money>500.00</Money>
    <Comments/>
  </InvoiceDetailOrder>
</cXML>
```